# How to get timestamp in VS code task?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm running small shell commands via tasks in VS code.

Within these commands I need the current timestamp.

Given I'm trying to run something like `mkdir ./%date` in a task:

```
{
    "label": "make timestamp dir",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "mkdir ${workspaceFolder}/%date%",
},
```

I tried using `%date%` and `%time%` but both is not substituted.

Alternatively I did see that VS code allows to call commands with `${command:CommandID}`.
Therefore I installed a extension that generates a timestamp: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsynowiec.vscode-insertdatestring
I tried to use that with `${command:insertDateString.insertTimestamp}`:

```
{
    "label": "make timestamp dir",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "mkdir ${workspaceFolder}/${command:insertDateString.insertTimestamp}",
},
```

But that also is not substituted.

I'm out of ideas.
**How to add a timestamp in a VS code task?**

Comment: Works in `echo %date%`. Is it not working because of var not being substituted, or `%date%` contains invalid chars for a windows folder name? C.f., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
  "command": "mkdir -p ${workspaceFolder}/`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`",
```

That bash command `date` works for me.  I assume you are using a unix-type shell and that'll work.  `-p` forces it to create the new folder if it doesn't already exist.

See also [in vscode how can I quickly generate a new file with datetime in the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699348/in-vscode-how-can-i-quickly-generate-a-new-file-with-datetime-in-the-name/60700104#60700104)

[I don't know that you want `${workspaceFolder}` -that appears to be a full path, maybe you want `${workspaceFolderBasename}` but that is a separate issue.]

Answer (score 0):

In arguments section I used forward slash (after two backslashes) as an escape char so, that following created me a folder with timestamp:

```
"args": ["${workspaceFolder}\\/%date:~-4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"]
```

Comment: You're right. It won't work when time is earlier than 10 a.m. because of %time:~0,2% -part. So, for example in 8.15 a.m. (today) foldername would be 20200205_ 81500 and VSCode don't understand it because there is that "empty slot" before number eight. After 10 a.m. it will work though but of course that's not a good solution.