# in vscode how can I quickly generate a new file with datetime in the name?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to be able to have a keyboard shortcut that creates a new file with the datetime as the prefix and some additional text that I enter.

I know there is a shortcut for generating a new file and I've seen snippets and extensions used to insert datetime into the editor but those extensions don't seem to work in the new filename dialog box.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use Marks `date` shell command if your shell has it, or you can use [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and use the `commandVariable.dateTime` command to construct a date-time string using JavaScript `Intl.DateTimeFormat` that uses Locals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.  I'm using the bash shell so you may have to modify the shell commands for your shell.

In tasks.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "newFile",
      "command": "touch `date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`-${input:fileName}.txt",

          // to create and open this new file use the following instead
      // "command": "touch `date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`-${input:fileName}.txt; code . `date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`-${input:fileName}.txt",

      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "silent",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": true
      },
      "promptOnClose": false
    }
  ],

  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "promptString",
      "id": "fileName",
      "description": "Complete my file name.",
      "default": "new file name"                  // make your default text here
    }
  ]
}
```

I used the bash commands `touch` and `date`, if you are using a non-unix type shell you'll have to modify that for your similar create a file and add timestamp commands.  And the file extension too (you could make that another promptString if you wish) - here jus hard-coded as `.txt`.

The task will create a new file with the timestamp as formatted followed by a pause for you to add the extra text you wanted to add.  See [task inputs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables).

The task could be run from the command palette `Run task` command or set a keybinding to run the task like this (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "newFile"
}
```

[image: create a file with timestamp]

[unix date examples](https://linuxhint.com/bash_date_examples/) and [more unix date formatting examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/)

Comment: Thanks very much Mark,  one follow up question - I noticed that while the file is created, vscode doesn't switch to make this the active editing window.  Do you have any suggestions on how I would add that functionality to this task?

Comment: any version for windows platform?

Comment: @KevinAuds The above works on Windows machines running a bash-like shell.  If you are using `cmd.exe` or `powershell` you will have to translate it into your shell commands.

Comment: @Mark  how to translate it into shell commands?

Answer (score 1):

maybe [espanso](https://github.com/federico-terzi/espanso) a text expander could give some help.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, I have this line in my alias which copies the date into your clipboard. You can also add this to your Alfred scripts.

```
alias today='date '+%m-%d-%Y' | pbcopy'
```